# Android Studio Rendering Error xml files

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting rendering error with `android...Toolbar`and `android...ConstraintLayout` in my xml files. However, in another application I am using exactly the same xml files and no problem occurs.

I am parallelly developing these two applications so not much things differ with each other yet I cannot understand it is doing this. I am using Android Studio 2.3.3.

Error:

```
Rendering failed with a known bug. Please try a rebuild.  

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  

Exception Details

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ViewBackgroundHelper
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatBackgroundHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatBackgroundHelper.java:46)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:73)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:66)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:475)
        at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:262)
        at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:213)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:193)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:333)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:152)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.NavigationBar.<init>(NavigationBar.java:52)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.NavigationBar.<init>(NavigationBar.java:46)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createNavBar(Layout.java:284)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:140)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:301)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
        at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please show the logcat

Comment: The app actually works however in the preview section of xml files it appears as if something is wrong..

Comment: Sure, but there'll be errors generated by the preview window

Comment: I have updated the question with the error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using the library of  **ConstraintLayout**...check in app:gradle

Comment: I have it already there. The problem is when I preview any xml file it appears as if there is some mistake but the app runs..

Comment: in logcat it says something about cache then try clearing it...and also try to rebuild the project without running on the device

Answer (score 0):

Being not 100% sure that my solution is stable, I simply replaced

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'` with `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'` and

`compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'` with `compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'`, their specific versions in app-level `build.gradle`.